# Sobreescribir un archivo ya descargado - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Soy nueva en python, he logrado encontrar este código para descargar algunos archivos TEC del siguiente link: 'ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gnss/products/ionex', el cual es el siguiente:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import re
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import wget
import subprocess
import matplotlib.cm
import matplotlib.colors

# Larger figure size
fig_size = [10, 10]
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = fig_size

def get_tecmaps(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        ionex = f.read()
        return [parse_map(t) for t in ionex.split('START OF TEC MAP')[1:]]

def ionex_filename(year, day, centre, zipped = True):
    return '{}g{:03d}0.{:02d}i{}'.format(centre, day, year % 100, '.Z' if zipped else '')

def ionex_ftp_path(year, day, centre):
    return 'ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gnss/products/ionex/{:04d}/{:03d}/{}'.format(year, day, ionex_filename(year, day, centre))

def ionex_local_path(year, day, centre = 'esa', directory = '/home/fernanda/gnss/esa/2018', zipped = False):
    return directory + '/' + ionex_filename(year, day, centre, zipped)

def download_ionex(year, day, centre = 'esa', output_dir = '/home/fernanda/gnss/esa/2018'):
    wget.download(ionex_ftp_path(year, day, centre), output_dir)
    subprocess.call(['gzip', '-d', ionex_local_path(year, day, centre, output_dir, zipped = True)])

for day in range(1, 366):
    download_ionex(2018, day)
```

Yo ya he ejecutado el archivo antes y tengo algunos datos descargados, sin embargo no son todos.
Cuando ejecuto de nuevo para descargar los datos que me faltan me sale lo siguiente:

fernanda@fernanda-astro:~/gnss/Data$ python example.py 
 63% [...........................gzip: /home/fernanda/gnss/esa/2018/esag0010.18i already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)?

Ante esto tengo que contestar con la letra "y" a cada archivo que ya existe. Mi pregunta es que debo agregar a al código para que cuando lo ejecute sobreescriba los archivos existentes y descarguen los otros sin tener que preguntarme si deseo sobreescribir los existentes.
A propósito estoy utilizando python 2.7.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Creo que debes agregar la opción **-f** al invocar gzip, quedando algo así: *subprocess.call(['gzip', '-df', ionex_local_path(year, day, centre, output_dir, zipped = True)])*